# Pomodoro timer for linux that I can install without admin rights

Tags: linux, productivity, timer, applet

What I need is a pomodoro timer (www.pomodorotechnique.com/) that I can use on a gnome linux (openSUSE) workstation that I use at work. It has to be able to show a popup notification so that I don't need to focus on the app and can see it whatever I'm doing. I can't install anything but I can use binaries in my /home/bin folder. I've tried various google-chrome apps/extensions but can't find anything which will give me pop-up notifications while google-chrome is minimised. It also has to be customisable (10 mins work, 2 mins break for example).

Anything out there that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GNOME 3, simply go to https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/53/pomodoro/ and install this extension.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share one of my scripts that enables me to do exactly this in Linux.

I've written a simple bash script, so you don't need any third-party software or installation. Just copy paste the code into a file and run it. The best part is that you can customize it as you imagine.

Here is the [link](https://gist.github.com/ManashRaja/3b72e7c79ded43f87280fd6e6baa56de)

Hope it helps.